# Array splicing issue in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

```
for each(var e:Enemy in enemies)
{
    if(e.getHealth() == 0)
    {
        enemies.splice(e,1);
    }
}
```

This code works fine as long as `enemies[0]` is being killed first. If `enemies[1]` is killed first, it splices both. How can I change this so only the specific enemy whose health hits 0 is being spliced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be splicing while traversing backwards. Brent has a good idea, but it can fail if two adjacent enemies need to be spliced out of the array, because those that are forward get their indexes shifted leftwards, thus, when the counter increments, an element that's right next to the one that got spliced is missed.

```
for (var i:int=enemies.length-1; i >=0 ; i--)
{
    if(enemies[i].getHealth() == 0)
    {
        enemies.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

With `for each` it's also possible, although the behavior might differ.

```
for each(var e:Enemy in enemies)
{
    if(e.getHealth() == 0)
    {
        enemies.splice(enemies.indexOf(e),1); // splice() wants an index
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did I not think of this to avoid re-indexing bugs?

Comment: @Brent I'm familiar with common bugs. Say Alpha Centauri has this, if a city got razed due to building a colony pod, the next one in the list does not produce/consume a thing (aka skipped from main cycle), due to exact this bug.

Comment: Time to rewrite some zombie despawn code then. This is the second thing I've learned on this thread alone.

Answer (score 1):

It's always hazardous to loop on an array you're modifying. The simpliest way in my opinion would be:

```
var aliveEnemies:Array = [];
for each(var e:Enemy in enemies)
{
    if(e.getHealth() > 0)
    {
        aliveEnemies.push(e);
    }
}
enemies = aliveEnemies;
```

Comment: This sounds like a waste of memory compared to splice. I guess it would depend on AS3's garbage collection which I assume is terrible and the number of deleted elements.

Comment: An Array is only storing its elements by reference. When you overwrite enemies, the references of dead enemies are lost and if you remove them from the display list and eventlisteners they will be collected. And since "enemies = aliveEnemies", aliveEnemies uses the same memory space as enemies.

Comment: The reason I don't like to use "i--" and backward loops is because it's not easily readable and maintainable, though intellectually satisfying.

Comment: You are increasing the memory usage of the enemies array by nearly double. The C++ or possibly C roots of the Flash player will more than likely be much faster and better at memory management than you can be within AS3. I would place money on the elements NOT being referenced and this can be tested by running for(var i:int=0;i<enemies.length;i++) enemies[i].setHealth(0); before you assign enemies to aliveEnemies. If the enemies are all dead, I stand corrected.

Comment: @Kodiak Brent says that an array too consumes memory, be it for references only. While yes, the actual set of enemy entities does not get cloned, the added array `aliveEnemies` eats some space, and most likely undergoes a large set of reallocs when adding enemies via push, as its length constantly increases.

Comment: I do agree, creating a new variable uses some memory. But I still prefer having an Array cleanly garbage collected later than spending 40 seconds reading a loop to understand what it does and what is left :)

Comment: I like this method of handling the situation. I've used all of these at one time or another, and can't say that I've ever run into an issue of speed or memory being a significant issue in regards to any of them. So, readability is a worthy plus.

Answer (score 0):

This will look through and delete any dead enemies. Note the for loop using the i variable which is where I assume you started. I wasn't sure how to get the index from a foreach loop in AS3.

```
for (var i:int=0; i < enemies.length; i++)
{
    if(enemies[i] && enemies[i].getHealth() == 0)
    {
        enemies.splice(i,1);
        i--;//index is re-stacked, next element is current element.
    }
}
```